# Jython: Parse JSON object to get value (object has array)

Tags: java, json, parsing, jython, maximo

I have JavaScript that parses a [JSON object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmJXS.png) (object has array) and returns the value from the `ZONE` field.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json_text);
parsed_val = obj.features[0].attributes.ZONE
```

I would like to **convert the JavaScript code** to **Jython**.

This is what I've tried:

```
from com.ibm.json.java import JSONObject

obj = JSONObject.parse(json_text)
parsed_val = obj.get('features.attributes.ZONE');
```

The Jython compiles, but it doesn't return a valid value (it returns `None`). I think this is because I haven't referenced the array properly.

How can I **parse the JSON object/array** using Jython to get the ZONE value?

*(Jython version is 2.7.0. However, I can't seem to use Python's JSON library (normally included in Jython)).*

Comment: *I am unable to add additional Python libraries to my system/server. Therefore, I believe I am limited to the Java libraries that are included in Jython/Maximo.*

Comment: You can add java libraries to the system but that creates other issues.  Google the java docs for the functions associated.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ja/SSEUEX_2.0.2/com.ibm.javaeuc.doc/com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject.html

Comment: Also, since it is obvious you are using a GIS endpoint, I would note that a lot can go wrong with your script if the GIS were to go down, move url, request gets lost, etc.  I discourage url links to GIS data except when already interacting with it graphically.  Always an exception though.

Comment: Try `.get('features').get('attributes').get('ZONE');`

Comment: @vikarjramun Thanks, but what about the array/index position (`0`)? Doesn't the code need to know which thing in the array to get?

Comment: @User1973 ah I didn't see that originally. I was just trying to translate what you included (`obj.get('features.attributes.ZONE')`) to something that would probably work. Idk how this specific json library works, maybe try `.get('features').get(0)...`, `.get('features')[0]...`. Either way, there will be a way to do it using this specific library, since JSON arrays are pretty common.

Comment: @Milton I'm attempting to address your **GIS vulnerability concerns** over on Code Review (thanks): [Work order spatial query (Part 2)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226786/work-order-spatial-query-part-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use `get()` at each level of the object.

As well as specify the array's index position after the first level: `[0]`.

```
from com.ibm.json.java import JSONObject

obj = JSONObject.parse(json_text)
parsed_val = obj.get("features")[0].get("attributes").get("WEEK")
```

Credit goes to **@vikarjramun** for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: The first `get()` was JSONObject's or JSONArray's `get()` method inherited from `Hashtable` or `HashMap` (I forget which), not Python's, depending on what came back from the `JSONObject.parse()` call. It would only be Python's method if you had done something to cast or coerce `obj` into a Python object.

Comment: Here are [IBM's JavaDocs for JSONObject](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEUEX_2.0.2/com.ibm.javaeuc.doc/com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject.html). It extends java.util.HashMap.