# How to interpret cryptic Java class documentation

Tags: java, json, documentation, maximo

I have a  Stack Overflow question where I'm attempting to use **Jython** to extract a field value from JSON text:

[Jython: Parse JSON object to get value (using Java functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617494/jython-parse-json-object-to-get-value-using-java-functions)

---

A Stack Overflow community member has been **kind enough** to point me towards some **Java documentation**:

> IBM >> Maximo >> [Class JSONObject (Java)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ja/SSEUEX_2.0.2/com.ibm.javaeuc.doc/com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject.html)

---

Unfortunately, I've been staring at the *Java documentation page* for hours now, and to be honest, **I have absolutely no idea what I'm looking at.**

Where does this documentation **show me** how to extract a value from JSON text?

*In other words, how do interpret this cryptic Java class documentation?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here, by passing the JSON string into the parse function.

[image: parse documentation]

Then, once you have your `JSONObject`, you can traverse the tree treating the object as a HashMap.

```
String jsonInput = "{ 'foo':'bar' }";
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.parse(jsonInput);
String fooValue = jsonObject.get('foo');
```

Of course, this is the hard way. You might consider a more fluid library like [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), which also has documentation that's more fluid.